# How do I change Windows 11 GUI direction from RTL to LTR?

Tags: windows-11, language, display-settings

My Windows 11 GUI is shown right-to-left, e.g., the "Start" button is at the right. I would like the GUI to be right-to-left. What I tried:

- In the "Display" Settings, there is an "Orientation" setting. But each of these options just rotated my display, and not changed the direction.
- In the "Language" Settings, I could change Windows' language from Hebrew to English, and it indeed changed the direction to LTR, but also changed the language to English.

Can I keep the language at Hebrew, but still change the GUI direction to LTR?

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 11 (Native Production, English language), no.  The Windows 11 GUI setup has been pretty much mandated by Microsoft.

The Start Button is part of the Task Bar (also now known as the Launcher) and the only orientations available are Left with the Start Button on the very left (my setup) or Center with the Start Button at the left end of the centered Launcher.

Further then, Language settings may change the orientation to Right to Left as you have seen.

However this is tied up in Languages and the Launcher limitations.

So stated in short: You need to use Windows 11 as it comes to you in your locale and language.